# Optimizing GROUP BY + jsonb_each on large table

Tags: postgresql, optimization, group-by, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize a request over a table using a jsonb field.

Here is my table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_insight (
  uuid UUID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  meta JSONB,
  data JSONB,
  insight_type_id UUID NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX ON data_insight ('insight_type_id');
CREATE INDEX ON data_insight ('meta');
```

In the `meta` column, I have filtering informations for the data in this table ; those filtering informations are unknown when I write my code and can vary from one insight to the other (depending on the `insight_type_id`).

What I need to get is the list of (key, values) from this `meta` column in order to let my user choose between them (with some filters applied). Currently, my request look like this:

```sql
SELECT "key", "value" FROM "data_insight"
LEFT JOIN jsonb_each("data_insight"."meta") ON TRUE
WHERE  "data_insight"."insight_type_id" = '64ff223c-be7d-435c-b83b-3649fa017f17'
GROUP BY "value", "key";
```

This request take up to 30 seconds to execute (there are around 4 million rows in the table, and a little less than 1 million of them are a part of the insight_type_id of my test request). Here is a result of an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` query for it:

```
Group  (cost=934323.86..934373.75 rows=100 width=64) (actual time=5403.970..5472.750 rows=435 loops=1)
  Group Key: jsonb_each.value, jsonb_each.key
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=934323.86..934371.75 rows=400 width=64) (actual time=5403.968..5470.881 rows=1938 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 4
        Workers Launched: 4
        ->  Sort  (cost=933323.80..933324.05 rows=100 width=64) (actual time=5190.508..5190.543 rows=388 loops=5)
              Sort Key: jsonb_each.value, jsonb_each.key
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 60kB
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 57kB
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 61kB
              Worker 2:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 58kB
              Worker 3:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 58kB
              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=933319.48..933320.48 rows=100 width=64) (actual time=5186.490..5186.782 rows=388 loops=5)
                    Group Key: jsonb_each.value, jsonb_each.key
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.81..823353.86 rows=21993125 width=64) (actual time=69.452..2962.023 rows=1399327 loops=5)
                          ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using data_insight_meta_insight_type_id_c54dbada_uniq on data_insight  (cost=0.81..383491.85 rows=219931 width=276) (actual time=69.278..751.725 rows=176904 loops=5)
                                Index Cond: (insight_type_id = '64ff223c-be7d-435c-b83b-3649fa017f17'::uuid)
                                Heap Fetches: 35500
                          ->  Function Scan on jsonb_each  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=100 width=64) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=8 loops=884519)
```

My questions:

1/ The time vary a lot in this request: sometimes it take 5-4 seconds, sometimes it take 30+ seconds. Is there something I should check to understand why?

2/ How could I make this request faster? I cannot remove the jsonb itself ; however, I thought about creating a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` to store the result of the jsonb_each (well, multiple of them actually, one per insight_type_id), would that help? Or would a simple `VIEW` be better?

Thank you

Comment: Create a properly normalized data model. No index will speed up `jsonb_each()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have no way to do that ; this table store varying data and I cannot know beforehand which columns will be there, and the columns themselves change with time. If I could create a normalized data model, I would :/

Comment: The index being used is not either of the ones you showed us being created.

Comment: @jjanes That's true ; i didn't include the names of the indexes as they were created by django and I didn't have the exact sql query used for them. It is the index named insight_type_id . Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

You are querying a large amount of data to get a small result.  That is never going to be blazing fast.  If you really need to do this, a materialized view is probably the best.  But you want to materialize *after* the group-by has massively deduplicated the data.

```
create materialized view insight_type_choices as
SELECT "data_insight"."insight_type_id", "key", "value" FROM "data_insight"
LEFT JOIN jsonb_each("data_insight"."meta") ON TRUE
GROUP BY "data_insight"."insight_type_id", "value", "key";
```

It seems unlikely that you actually do want that join to really be a LEFT JOIN, but I left it that way since that is how you wrote it.  I would throw a count column on there as well, because it would basically be free and if it ever generates thousands of options, you will probably want a way to rank them.